# How to get Azure DevOps pipeline manual cancellation call back

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I am using Azure DevOps pipeline to run some jobs. This pipeline has been created using YML.

As I am calling to Azure data factory pipeline using my DevOps pipeline, so if a user manually cancell DevOps pipeline, in that case my Azure Data Factory still in running mode which should ideally not happened.

Is there a way to stop my azure data factory pipeline autmatically whenever there is cancellation of Azure DevOps pipeline from UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, We could add task power shell task and set the [custom condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) `canceled()`, this task will only run if you cancel the build.

[image]

Then add power shell script to call [the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/cancel) to cancel the Azure Data Factory pipeline.

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelineruns/{runId}/cancel?api-version=2018-06-01
```

Also, we could do this via webhook, you could also check this [blog](https://cloudsafari.ca/2020/09/data-engineering/Azure-DataFactory-Cancel-Pipeline-Run) and update the json.